# Laravel Artisan - reload .env variables or restart framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to write a command as a quickstart to build a project. The command asks for input for database details and then changes the .env file. The problem is that the command needs to do some Database queries afterwards, but the .env variables are not reloaded.

My question would be, is there a way to reload or override .env variables runtime. And if not, is there a way to call another Artisan command *freshly*, so framework bootstraps again?

In my command I tried doing `$this->call('build:project')` in my actual command, but even in the second call the variables are not reloaded.

Is there a way to achieve this without making the user manually call multiple commands?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your command that changes the .env file?

Comment: It's a simple str_replace in a file:
`file_put_contents(base_path('.env'), str_replace($from, $to, file_get_contents(base_path('.env'))));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel uses config files which take data from `.env` file. So, what you can do is to [override configuration values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) at runtime:

```
config(['database.default' => 'mysql']);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I change the `.env` file and then do `config(['database.username' => $dbuser]);` and call `$this->call('migrate');` and still receive error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'` even though I did not enter `forge` and it's not that in the `.env` file (it is by default in the `database` config).

Comment: @Giedrius, because there is no `databade.username` property. Try this: `config(['database.connections.mysql.username' => 'root'])`

Comment: my bad, rushed into it! This worked perfectly and the migrations are running now, thank you.

Comment: i am having the same problem and it is not working :( i am setting `database.connections.sqlsrv.database`, `database.connections.pgsql.database`, `database.connections.mysql.database`, `database.connections.sqlite.database` to the new values, then event print the whole config() and it clearly says that the config is new but when i run `this->call('migrate')`, i am still getting database trying to use the default database and not my new one :(

Comment: @user151496 are you doing this in the same request?

Comment: yes, it is running in a console Command (wanted to make an installation script that asks user for database info). what is even more surprising, if i create a new db connection profile like `database.connections.somethingnew.*` and call migration with specific database parameters like this `Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => 'somethingnew'])` it works! but if i re-set the old vlues of `database.connections.pgsql.*` it keeps the old values. i tried `cache:clear` and `config:clear` without any success. makes me think it's a laravel bug

Answer (score 13):

i had the same problem with reloaded .env variables, and i fixed it with this command line which allow you to clear the configuration :

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope that helped. Regards.

Comment: and just how did you reload the .env variables in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache it helped me (couldn't ssh into the server)

Is there a {app route}/bootstrap/cache/config.php file on the production server? Delete it.

This helped me

Answer (score 0):

As OP I'm trying to bootstrap a Laravel project build by running console command and asking for the database credentials in the middle of the process.

This is a tricky problem and nothing I read was able to fix it : reset config, cache, Dotenv reload, etc... It seems that once the console command / operation is initialized the initial database connection is kept all over until the end.

The working solution I found is to bypass, after database modification are done, this cached state by using native shell exec command and passing the php artisan command as parameter :

```
passthru('php artisan migrate');
```

So, the order will be :

1. php artisan project:build (or whatever is your console command)
2. prompt the user for database credentials
3. replace values in .env file (your search & replace algorythm)
4. run `php artisan config:cache`
5. `passthru('php artisan migrate');` ro run your migrations

`shell_exec` would do the same but in silent mode while `passthru` will return the output generated by console.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Done successfully on Laravel 8.52